SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN only via google
I have installed Odoo running in a docker container and I'm using an nginx reverse proxy to make it accessible. I used certbot to generate lets encrypt certificates.
I basically followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-odoo-with-docker-on-ubuntu
Everything seems to be working fine.
www.website.com works and is redirected to https://website.com
http://website.com works and is redirected to https://website.com
http://www.website.com works and is redirected to https://website.com
https://website.com works and is redirected to https://website.com
https://www.website.com works and is redirected to https://website.com
But, when i google the website in FIREFOX and I click the link on google, it shows up this error:

Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust
this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for
www.website.com. The certificate is only valid for
website.com.   Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

It does work in Chrome (at least for me...)
This is my nginx file (etc/nginx/sites-available/odoo.conf):
server {
    server_name  website.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:10015;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}
server {
    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = www.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

When I try to run:
certbot --nginx -d website.com -d www.website.com
I get this error:
root@ubuntudocker:~# certbot --nginx -d website.com -d www.website.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Cert not yet due for renewal

You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/website.com.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
2: Renew & replace the cert (limit ~5 per 7 days)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Renewing an existing certificate
Deploying Certificate to VirtualHost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/odoo.conf
Could not automatically find a matching server block for www.website.com. Set the `server_name` directive to use the Nginx installer.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Unable to install the certificate
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2024-12-05. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again
   with the "certonly" option. To non-interactively renew *all* of
   your certificates, run "certbot renew"

Any ideas on what's wrong or things I should check?
I'm not an expert at this and can't seem to figure it out...
